# Not compile in x86_32 ( error _ impossible contraint in __asm__ )

Tags: linux, gcc, assembly

I write this code in x86_64 and compile and run well ,

```
    __asm__("nop"
            : "=eax"(foo)
            : //"eax"(foo),"ebx"(bar)
            : "eax"
    );
```

but when I try to compile in other machine ( x86_32) gcc trigger an error :S

```
   inline1.c:6: error: impossible constraint in _asm_
```

I can't fix it.. :S

GCC versions ::

**NOT COMPILE** :

```
   tur@aso:~$ gcc -v
   Using built-in specs.
   Target: i486-linux-gnu
   Configured with: ../src/configure -v --with-pkgversion='Ubuntu 4.4.3-4ubuntu5.1' --                     with-bugurl=file:///usr/share/doc/gcc-4.4/README.Bugs --enable-       languages=c,c++,fortran,objc,obj-c++ --prefix=/usr --enable-shared --enable-multiarch --       enable-linker-build-id --with-system-zlib --libexecdir=/usr/lib --without-included-gettext --enable-threads=posix --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.4 --program-suffix=-4.4 --enable-nls --enable-clocale=gnu --enable-libstdcxx-debug --enable-plugin --enable-objc-gc --enable-targets=all --disable-werror --with-arch-32=i486 --with-tune=generic --enable-checking=release --build=i486-linux-gnu --host=i486-linux-gnu --target=i486-linux-gnu
```

Thread model: posix
gcc version 4.4.3 (Ubuntu 4.4.3-4ubuntu5.1)

**COMPILE**

```
   git@srvcode:/home/git/code/asm$ gcc -v
   Using built-in specs.
   COLLECT_GCC=gcc
   COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.6.1/lto-wrapper
   Target: x86_64-linux-gnu
   Configured with: ../src/configure -v --with-pkgversion='Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.1-       9ubuntu3' --with-bugurl=file:///usr/share/doc/gcc-4.6/README.Bugs --enable-languages=c,c++,fortran,objc,obj-c++,go --prefix=/usr --program-suffix=-4.6 --enable-shared --enable-linker-build-id --with-system-zlib --libexecdir=/usr/lib --without-included-gettext --enable-threads=posix --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.6 --libdir=/usr/lib --enable-nls --with-sysroot=/ --enable-clocale=gnu --enable-libstdcxx-debug --enable-libstdcxx-time=yes --enable-plugin --enable-objc-gc --disable-werror --with-arch-32=i686 --with-tune=generic --enable-checking=release --build=x86_64-linux-gnu --host=x86_64-linux-gnu --target=x86_64-linux-gnu
```

Thread model: posix
gcc version 4.6.1 (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.1-9ubuntu3)

Thanks for all!!

Artur.

Comment: Why are you not using gcc-4.6 for the 32 bit compile as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`nop` is a no-operand instruction. If you don't have any operands used in the inline, then gcc isn't able to assign any registers to the operands used, which is probably why setting any input/output registers fails. No registers are modified by the instruction, though, so I'm very curious why you think `eax` needs to be preserved.

Secondly, in older versions of gcc, a register cannot be on both the input/output list and the clobber list. Registers on input/output lists are of course naturally assumed to be "clobbered". You're best off adjusting to that behaviour for backwards compatibility.

Also, you should remember that register operands in inline assembly aren't specified using their actual names (except the clobber list). Instead, a single letter describing the register is used. So, we have `a` for `eax`, `b` for `ebx`, and so on. You also probably want to read the [GCC Inline Assembly HOWTO](http://www.ibiblio.org/gferg/ldp/GCC-Inline-Assembly-HOWTO.html), it's a great resource for information on the subject.

Summing it all up, something like that should work much better :

```
__asm__("nop"
        : /* no output */
        : /* no input */
        : "%eax" /* eax is clobbered */
);
```

Comment: I'm writing a kernel module that should catch syscalls and his parameters ( parameters are in registers)